# Как очистить поле ввода сообщения после отправки сообщения

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net-core

Учусь по примеру: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Как после отправки сообщения очищать поле messageInput?
Поле, которое необходимо очистить messageInput:

```
<div class="col-6">
            User <input type="text" id="userInput" />
            <br />
            Message <input type="text" id="messageInput" />
            <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
</div>
```

В файле Chat.js в функцию connection.on пробовал добавить:

document.getElementsById('messageInput').value = '';

```js
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    document.getElementsByID('messageInput')[0].value = '';
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: А ошибок в консоли никаких не возникает? Не верю, ведь метода getElementsById не существует.

Comment: в консоли ошибок нет

Comment: Значит, вы что-то недоговариваете.

Answer (score 1):

Функция getElementsByName возвращает массив, поэтому нужно добавить обращение к первому элементу массива

```
document.getElementsByName('messageInput')[0].value = '';
```

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало